# Are there reliable Rav Hamchshir for certified pre-owned Hondas?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In my neighborhood, many of my frum neighbors drive Honda Odysseys. They are a popular minivan esp. for families with lots of kids.

I asked someone about her car and what it costs. She said that she bought a "certified" pre-owned Honda. She told me where she bought hers from and even though it is certified, my rav doesn't trust their certification, and told me not to use it.

I couldn't find a list of rabbanim who certify Odysseys. Does anyone know if there is a list around, or know any reliable rav who certifies pre-owned Honda Odysseys?

I would offer you a referral commission, but, it may take me a while to pay up.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: You ask a good question. I don't have a source but I seem to recall that this urban legend began in the mid-to-late 00's  when a rabbi from Moscow misinterpreted when a Russian-Jew living in Hamburg told him that their rabbi was upset that they were driving their Odessey at top speed on the aütobahn. The rabbi from Moscow did not understand the young German Jews' broken Russian and thought that the rabbi in Hamburg placed an "auto ban" on the Honda Odessey.

Comment: @JJLL Sounds like that could be an answer to me

Comment: @shokhet Thank you for the suggestion. I'll submit it as such.

Answer (score 4):

My response above is being transferred here as an answer as suggested by @shokhet:

You ask a good question. I don't have a source but I seem to recall that this urban legend began in the mid-to-late 00's when a rabbi from Moscow misinterpreted when a Russian-Jew living in Hamburg told him that their rabbi was upset that they were driving their Odessey at top speed on the aütobahn. The rabbi from Moscow did not understand the young German Jews' broken Russian and thought that the rabbi in Hamburg placed an "auto ban" on the Honda Odessey.

Answer (score 3):

Anything called Odyssey is tainted by suspicion of *chochmos chitzoniyos*. Furthermore, both Honda (a parking meter-wielding sumo wrestler from a video game) and Odysseus (a fraudster and thief of truly Talmudic proportions) are horrible role models for Jews. As such, the Honda Odyssey is completely *treif* and any Rav certifying one is misleading the unsuspecting Orthodox public and should be ashamed to call himself a Rabbi. He might as well be a used car salesman!

Comment: @Yitchak - Watch it! We have a rabbi in our neighborhood who IS a used car salesman. I trust him for halachic matters, but to recommend cars? Ehhhh ...

Answer (score 2):

This question is so appropriate for this time of the year. Esther was also known as הדסה which is a derivative of Odyssey. The Rav who endorses Honda's is from Honduras also known as the Honda Rav.